# Combine two arrays with the same value to key

Tags: php, arrays

I have first array called `$monthsNumber`

```
$monthsNumber = array(
                       0 => 2,
                       1 => 4,
                       2 => 5
                     )
```

I have second array called `$monthsName`

```
$monthsName = array(
                     1 => 'January',
                     2 => 'February',
                     3 => 'March',
                     4 => 'April',
                     5 => 'May',
                     6 => 'June',
                     7 => 'July',
                     8 => 'August', 
                     ...
                     12 => 'December'
                   )
```

In first step user can choose months (`$monthsNumber`).
I want to get third array that will be combined with these two and will contain:

```
$outputArr = array(
               0 => 'March',
               1 => 'May',
               2 => 'June')
```

Keys in the last array are not important- it can be anything.

I tried array_merge, array_intersect_key and array_intersect_assoc - doesn't work.

note that the keys in the first array are not the same as in the second one

I can't explain it much more, sorry :)

Comment: Ok, question is a little Too Broad, but fairly simple, so what have you tried

Comment: You're looking for [**`array_merge()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: I tried array_merge, array_intersect_key and array_intersect_assoc - doesn't work :(

Comment: How do the values in `$monthsNumber` correspond to `$monthsName`?

Comment: Why don't you create a form with month names already on it?

Comment: `$monthsNumber` is from API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the *values* of the `$monthsNumber` array to match on the *index* of `$monthsName` and you only want to filter a single value from `$monthsName`.
You can apply `array_flip` to `$monthsNumber` to allow the use of `array_intersect_key` to match the keys of `$monthsName`. Acting as a whitelist of allowed values.

Example: https://3v4l.org/IDJdU

```
$monthsFiltered = array_intersect_key($monthsName, array_flip($monthsNumber));

print_r($monthsFiltered);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => February
    [4] => April
    [5] => May
)
```

To remove the retained index from `$monthsName`, you can wrap the above with `array_values(...)`

```
$monthsFiltered = array_values($monthsFiltered);
print_r($monthsFiltered);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => February
    [1] => April
    [2] => May
)
```

---

If you need to retrieve multiple of the identical `$monthsName` values, you can use `array_map` on `$monthsNumber`. To retrieve the desired values of `$monthsName` passing it with `use()` to the callback function and verifying the index exists.

Dataset: `$monthsNumber = [2, 4, 5, 2, 2];`

Example: https://3v4l.org/ObOkI

```
$monthsFiltered = array_map(function($v) use($monthsName) {
    return isset($monthsName[$v]) ? $monthsName[$v] : false;
}, $monthsNumber);

print_r($monthsFiltered);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => February
    [1] => April
    [2] => May
    [3] => February
    [4] => February
)
```

---

Otherwise you can also build your desired array values using `foreach`.

Example: https://3v4l.org/Loapt

```
$monthsFiltered = [];
foreach ($monthsNumber as $v) {
    if (isset($monthsName[$v]) && !in_array($monthsName[$v], $monthsFiltered)) {
        $monthsFiltered[] = $monthsName[$v];
    }
}

print_r($monthsFiltered);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => February
    [1] => April
    [2] => May
)
```

Comment: It's definitely enough for me :)... simple and hiting in point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using `array_map` to process the elements of `$monthsNumber`:

```
$outputArr = array_map(function ($m) use($monthsName) { return $monthsName[$m+1]; }, $monthsNumber);
print_r($outputArr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => March
    [1] => May
    [2] => June
)
```

Comment: Why the need for the `global` variables? What's wrong with using `use` instead?

Comment: @fubar the difference is, use function will take the value of definition, and global will take the current value of execution. 

For this scenario, we can use any which has no difference. Because of no modification of value.

Comment: @DhayalRam you can pass by reference using `&` like `function($m) use(&$monthsName)`

Comment: @fubar you are right that is more appropriate in this scenario. I have edited the post to reflect that.